# As per GDPR, can i request the creation date of an account i made on a website on a legal base?

Tags: gdpr

Basically title, i want to know when i created my Microsoft account, they replied saying that this info is part of the verification process and thus they cant give it to me.

Comment: Interesting. As per their reply, they do store this pieve of information about you. And since it is specifically used to verify / identify you, it is personal data. So at first glance this certainly seems to be data you are entitled to request under GDPR.

Comment: In support of @HagenvonEitzen's comment, Microsofts process for validating the identity of a subject requesting their data in accordance with the GDPR should take this into account - they can't block you from accessing your data under the GDPR by solely requiring you to verify the data they hold, they should be able to verify your identity and your link to the data without doing that.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

You are retirement to all the information stored as partm of your account, which would include the date of storage.